# How is serviceUrl of a bot (created using MS bot framework) decided

Tags: azure, botframework

I recently moved my MS bot code (created using MS bot framework into my new laptop). However, in emulator, there is a difference in behavior in two laptops.

The bot is hosted in azure cloud as an app service.

In my old laptop, when I send a message, the serviceUrl is set to an ngrok URL (I dont know how, that what I am trying to figure out).

In my new laptop, I am not able to test the bot in new laptop and emulator keeps on complaining

```
[03:51:09] Error: The bot is remote, but the callback URL is localhost. Without tunneling software you will not receive replies. 
[03:51:09] Connecting to bots hosted remotely 
[03:51:09] Edit ngrok settings 
[03:51:09] Error: The bot is remote, but the callback URL is localhost. Without tunneling software you will not receive replies. 
[03:51:09] Connecting to bots hosted remotely 
[03:51:09] Edit ngrok settings 
[03:51:11] -> POST 200 [conversationUpdate] 
[03:51:11] -> POST 200 [conversationUpdate] 
[03:51:15] Error: The bot is remote, but the callback URL is localhost. Without tunneling software you will not receive replies. 
[03:51:15] Connecting to bots hosted remotely 
[03:51:15] Edit ngrok settings 
[03:51:16] -> POST Request to 'https://something.azurewebsites.net/api/messages' failed: [500] Internal Server Error
```

I have edited ngrok settings to give it a path to ngrok exe.

Can any one tell me how the service url is decided? I am not sure why it works on one laptop but not on the other one.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused if you mean **endpoint** or **serviceUrl** ngrok would never be use for a serviceUrl.

Comment: `Without tunneling software` After you configure the path of ngrok on emulator **App Settings**, please make sure you click **SAVE**. Besides, earlier versions might be incompatible, please check the version of your ngrok.

Answer (score 1):

First ensure you are running a version of ngork 2.1.18 or newer, then , Open the emulator's App Settings dialog, enter the path to ngrok, select whether or not to bypass ngrok for local addresses, and click Save.[image]

I'd recommend checking the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-debug-emulator), it has more details about the setup.